# Loading JSON into Hbase and modelling the database

Tags: json, hbase

I have more than 600GB of data. I want to load this data into HBase and build a restful service for serving the data.

The data  have is the of the following format

file1:

```
{key1:value1, key2:value2 .......}

{key1:value3, key2:value4 .......}
.................................
  (arbitary number of entries)
.................................
```

file2:

```
{key1:value5, key2:value6 .......}

{key1:value7, key2:value8 .......}
.................................
  (arbitary number of entries)
.................................
```

..............................................................................

(large number of files like this)

..............................................................................

One of the keys is `id` key and one more `timestamp` key. In my RESTful service, the request should take in `id` and `timestamp` and return the entries(in all of 600GB data set).

I am confused about couple of things

1. I have mainly worked with Postgres and MySQL (RDBMS Databases), but have slightly worked with CouchDB(not proficient). I am confused how should I model my Hbase database considering my requirements.
2. What exactly is the procedure to load into Hbase given it is in the format mentioned above.

Comment: do you plan to build your own rest service or using hbase built-in rest service aka stargate?

Comment: @averman , yes I plan to build my own rest service , not HBase default